# My Call Spring Controller failed

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

In my HTML i have this button:

```
<button id="download_button">Confirmer</button>
```

In my Js i have this method:

```
$("#download_button").click(function() {
   downloadMes();
});

    downloadMes: function(){
        var sources = this.map.getLayers().getArray().map(function(layer){
            var source_url = layer.getSource().getUrls()[0];
            var layer_name = layer.getSource().getParams()['LAYERS'];
            var request = '?VERSION=1.1.0&OUTPUTFORMAT=CSV';
            if(_.includes(this.downloadSources, source_url)){
                return source_url + request + '&TYPENAME=' + layer_name;
            }
        },this);
        var sourcesToCall = _.compact(sources);
        var jsonfile= {json:JSON.stringify(sourcesToCall)};
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: "/downloadCSV",
            data: jsonfile,
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
```

I have create a Spring Controller --> DownloadCSVController :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
public class DownloadCSVController {



    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model) throws IOException{

        System.out.println("DEBUT TELECHARGEMENT");
        // SOME LOGIC
        System.out.println("FIN TELECHARGEMENT");

    }
}
```

When i click on my button i have this error :

> POST http://localhost:8080/downloadCSV 404 (Introuvable)

What is wrong?

Comment: change $ajax type in js to get or post in spring

Comment: since you are posting data, you need to change the controller method  to method=RequestMethod.POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ajax call to GET method like this

```
$.ajax({
            type:'GEt',
            url: "/downloadCSV",
            data: jsonfile,
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

OR change spring controller method to post

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void getCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model) throws IOException{

        System.out.println("DEBUT TELECHARGEMENT");
        // SOME LOGIC
        System.out.println("FIN TELECHARGEMENT");

    }
```

PS: if your project has some root folder and based on dispatcher servlet url mapping also specified its name while request something like localhost:8080/yourproject/downloadCSV

Comment: yes i have a root foolder where i specified this, in my ajax or in my controller
root folder: `project-web`

Comment: in the ajax call /yourfolder/downloadCSV

Comment: prior to that what is your dispatcher servlet url mapping ?

Comment: i do't understant

Comment: in your web.xml what is url mapping of org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Comment: `<servlet>
  <servlet-name>gestion</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-gestion-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>`

Comment: there will be one tag <url-pattern> in your gestion servlet please give that value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122891/discussion-between-mercer-and-jekin-kalariya).

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to post data to get url. So change your controller and try this

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
public class DownloadCSVController {



    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void getCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody ModelMap model) throws IOException{

        System.out.println("DEBUT TELECHARGEMENT");
        // SOME LOGIC
        System.out.println("FIN TELECHARGEMENT");

    }
}
```